# SoftDeletes Memory issue with php 7.4 and Illuminate 7.9.2

Tags: eloquent, php-7.4

We have a project with eloquent (without Laravel).

Recently we upgrade to php 7.4, and then Iluminate/database to 7.9.2

In seeder, when we insert data into model without SofDelete, it works.

But when model have softdelete, it hangs.

Example Role:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Role extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'usuarios_roles';
    public $timestamps = true;
...
```

```
$admin = Role::create(array(
        'nombre'         => 'Admin',
        'vista'          => '1',
        'path'           => '/admin/clientes/',
        'editables'      => 0
    ));
```

Works fine.

Example User:

```
require_once('EloquentRegAcc.php');
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Usuario extends EloquentRegAcc
{

    use SoftDeletes;
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $table = 'usuarios';
...
```

```
$usuario_admin = Usuario::create(array(
        'id_role'       => $admin2->id,
        'nombre'        => 'Admin',
        'email'         => $email,
        'password'      => $password2,
        'permissions'   => '{}'
    ));
```

It give us an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 4294967296 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /home/vagrant/code/project/vendor/illuminate/database/Eloquent/SoftDeletes.php on line 36
```

We try to upgrade Vagrant RAM, from 2GB to 4GB, and set ini_set('memory_limit', '4096M') , but no way.

In the database we have roles, but not users.

Same code with php 7.1 and Iluminate/database 5.x works fine.

not matter if is user or other table; if model have SoftDelete, hangs.

Answer (score 0):

We have a "homemade" log in the app.

If we change

```
require_once('EloquentRegAcc.php');
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class Usuario extends EloquentRegAcc
{
```

To

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class Usuario extends Eloquent
{
```

Works as spect. We need to rewrite or log.